# Can i get a backup of ubuntu?

Tags: backup

I'm getting a new computer soon and I want to know how to get a backup of my Ubuntu system, and transfer it over to my new computer? How do i do that?

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem. Personally I only back up my data in /home and any system configuration files I edit + a list of installed packages.

Comment: if you want to backup entire system - do what Wild Man said, if only personal dat - do what bodhi.zazen said :) 

blue pill or red pill (the matrix :) )

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have found is clonezilla, it will make a complete backup which is actually an image and restore it to your new drive.
Here is a link [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)